# Question on Projectile Motion equation

Tags: projectile, free-fall, kinematics

> A golf ball is shot into the air from the ground. If the initial
>   horizontal velocity is 20m/s and the initial vertical velocity is
>   30m/s, what is the horizontal distance the ball will travel before it
>   hits the ground?

Ans: The golf ball will continue to travel through air until gravity brings it back down to the ground. Under the gravity force, the vertical location of the ball as a function of time is given by the following equation:-
$$ z = z_0 + v_{z_0} t - \frac{1}{2} g t^2 $$

The time it takes the golf ball to return the ground is equal to
$$ T = \frac{2v_{z_0}}{g} $$

The horizontal distance the ball will travel before it hits the ground can be computed using the following equation:-
$$ \Delta x = x-x_0 = v_{x_0} t = 2 v_{x_0} v_{z_0} / g = 122.4\text{ m} $$

The problems are:

1) what is the parameter $v$ represent?

2) In the example above $ \Delta x = x-x_0 = v_{x_0} t = 2 v_{x_0} v_{z_0} / g = 122.4\text{ m} $ What is the actual value in this equation? So that $x=?$ $x_0=?$ $v=30?$ $g=10?$ $z0=?$

Comment: Welcome to Physics.SE, Leo. I've re-formatted you post to take advantage of the MathJax formatting engine which is running on the site. I've also closed it because it appears to violate [our site policy on answering specific introductory exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#questions). If you can reformulate this in terms of the concepts that you are struggling with we can either point you at an existing answered question of re-open this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your formatting is messing things up.  There are two v's, $v_{x0}$ (i.e horizontal velocity) and $v_{z0}$ (i.e. vertical velocity at $t = 0$).  You can get these values right out of the problem statement.  Also, $g$ is 9.8m/s.  Lastly, $x$ is insignificant; you only need to find $\Delta x$ (even if you were given $x$ it wouldn't effect your final answer).

Comment: Thanks, is the first 2 equation mentioned in my question not relevant to the answer?